# How do I display calories from fat percent in Java

Tags: java

Newbie here with 2 questions.

Question 1:
Where the program asks for the amount of calories, the operator in the  "while" portion of the code is supposed to keep asking for the amount of calories until both sides of the operator is true. It is not. How do I fix that? example... If I enter fat at 20, and calories at 100, It should ask me again and again until I enter 180 or more (20 * 9).

Question 2:
I receive this error message after the getCalories function is completed:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at fatGramCalculator.main(fatGramCalculator.java:19)"
I understand you can not divide by zero but I thought when I entered fat at 20 it remained as the value of fat throughout the program?

Sorry kind of lengthy but I feel like I am very close to the working. Thank you for any and all feedback.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fatGramCalculator{

static int fat, calorie, fatPercent;

//Module main
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Calls getFat function
    getFat(fat);

    //Calls getCalories function
    getCalories(calorie);

    //shows percent of fat
    fatPercent = ((fat * 9) / calorie);
    System.out.println("The percent of calories from fat is " + fatPercent + ".");

}

//getFat function
static int getFat(int fat){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    System.out.println("What is the amount of fat grams?");
    fat = keyboard.nextInt();
    }while (fat < 0);
    
    return fat;
}
//getCalories function
static int getCalories(int calorie){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    System.out.println("What is the amount of calories?");
    calorie = keyboard.nextInt();
    }while ((calorie >= fat * 9) && (calorie <= 0));
    
    return calorie;
}
```

}

Comment: `while ((calorie >= fat * 9) && (calorie <= 0))` <- This means "Keep looping as long as calorie is bigger than fat*9 and calorie is less than or equal to zero." Since fat is a positive number this condition cannot be fulfilled ever. The number calorie cannot both be 0 or less and also more than 0 at the same time. You probably meant to use OR instead of AND for this condition

Comment: To make sure I understand, the do-while statement will continue to ask for calories until the while conditions are both false, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: the `calorie` variable you are using in the getCalories has a method scope, so basically you need to assign the returned value from it to your static variable
In the main method :

```
fat = getFat();
calorie = getCalories();
```

And also don't pass it arguments, it seems kinda pointless because you are getting the value from keyboard input.

Question 2: global value declared as static calorie if not assigned anything will be 0, and you are not assigning it any value. Default int value is 0.

Don't worry for being newbie, keep coding :)

Comment: And the other problem is that because of integer division, the result will still always be zero unless fat calories is greater than total calories, which should be impossible.

Comment: I think what is happening is when I enter in the number of fat "20" then enter in calories "200" the code does not save 20 as my value of fat for the while loop. it is being changed back to 0 and that is why I am getting the error, right?